# Find vector vertical to given vector of R^4

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products

Given the vector

> **a**=(5,6,7,13)

find all the vectors vertical to it.

Let's say that the vector

> **c**=(x,y,z,w)

is the vector we want to find.
Then,

> **a c** = 0
>
> <=> 5x + 6y + 7z + 13w = 0

What I can do in addition to this to give the answer?
Could you help, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can express $x=-\dfrac{6}{5}y-\dfrac{7}{5}z-\dfrac{13}{5}w.$ Denote $y=5\alpha$, $z=5\beta$, $w=5\gamma$ and your solutions are: $$\mathbf{c}=(-6\alpha-7\beta-13\gamma,\;5\alpha,\;5\beta,\;5\gamma)\quad \alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: Thank you. I think you mean 5α,5β, 5γ in the parenthesis, right?

Comment: Of course (typos). I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

By "vertical", I think you mean orthogonal.

You have obtained the answer already, you just have to write it in set notation:

$\{(x,y,z,w)^T\in\mathbb{R}^4\mid5x + 6y + 7z + 13w = 0\}$

If you want a particular vector, you can set arbitrary values for $x,y,z$ and then solve for $w$.

For instance, you can choose $x=0,y=0,z=1$. This forces $7+13w=0$, so $w=-7/13$.

So a particular orthogonal vector is $(0,0,1,-7/13)$.